# Two separate deploy configurations on travis

Tags: node.js, deployment, electron, travis-ci

```
os:
  - osx
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '12'
dist: xenial
services:
  - xvfb
before_script:
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
install:
  - npm set progress=false
  - npm install
script:
  - ng lint
  - npm run build:electron
deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key: "$GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN"
  file_glob: true
  file:
    - "release/*.dmg"
    - "release/*.dmg.blockmap"
  name: Build $(date +'%d.%m.%Y %R')
```

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '12'
branches:
  only:
    - web-app
before_script:
  - npm install -g @angular/cli
script:
  - npm install
  - npm run build
deploy:
  skip_cleanup: true
  provider: firebase
  token:
    secure: ""
```

I have two config files for travis.
How to merge them?

I tried different ways, but it makes errors like: 'duplicate deploy keyword'.

I want to deploy first part from branch `master` and second from `web-app`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and populate a Dockerfile.dev file with your first code block and populate the second code block into a Dockerfile. Then create a docker-compose.yml file (still in your root directory) it would connect and run both files

something structured like this

version: '3'
services:
  web:
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - "1500:1500"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app